# RaspbianでWi-Fiの接続ができるとき・できないときがある

Tags: raspberry-pi, ssh, wifi

USBキーボードを接続しているとき、接続していないときでwlan0のIPアドレスが
取得できる・できないの症状が発生しています。

確認すべきことやヒントなどを教えていただけると幸いです。

**症状**
RaspberryPi3 BにUSBキーボードを接続して起動・再起動をするとSSHで接続ができる
（DHCPサーバーからwlan0にIPアドレスが付与される）
USBキーボードを外して起動するとSSHで接続ができない。

起動画面では下記のメッセージが表示されて

```
Started LSB: Switch to ondemand cpu governor (unless shift key is pressed).
Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
Started Bluetooth service.
Reached target Bluetooth.
Started Raspberry Pi bluetooth helper.
         Starting Hostname Service...
Started Hostname Service.
 A start job is running for dhcpcd on all interfaces (49s / 1min 32s)
```

カウントアップが始まりIPアドレスが取得できずにログイン画面が表示される。

**動作環境**
Raspberry Pi3 B
Raspbian (stretch), 2018-11-13-raspbian-stretch-lite.img
Windows10からSSHで接続して使っています。

```
# uname -a
Linux myweb 4.14.79-v7+ #1159 SMP Sun Nov 4 17:50:20 GMT 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: 追記された部分は問題が解決したということでしょうか？もしそうであれば、質問文に対してではなくぜひ個別の**回答**として投稿を行ってみてください。スタック・オーバーフローでは自己回答も歓迎です。

Comment: ヒントを頂いたことで、解決策がわかりました。
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/51231/15346

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raspbianのセキュリティのため、キーボードやモニターが接続されていないとWiFiが使えないことがわかりました。

下記の手順にてキーボード、モニタの接続なしでもWiFi接続ができるようにサービスを登録しました。

```
# cp /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf

# systemctl disable wpa_supplicant.service

# systemctl enable wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service

# systemctl list-unit-files | grep wpa_supplicant
  wpa_supplicant-wired@.service          disabled
  wpa_supplicant.service                 disabled
  wpa_supplicant@.service                enabled

# reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

セキュリティ上の理由でディスプレイやキーボードがつながっていない状態だと(デフォルトでは)sshが有効とならないようです。

対応としては、SDカードの`/boot/`ディレクトリ直下に`ssh`という名前の空ファイルを配置して起動すれば`ssh`が有効となるようです。

参考：
[Raspberry Pi 3(Raspbian)をディスプレイなしでセットアップする方法](https://memoteki.net/archives/1341)
[Raspberry Piをディスプレイ・キーボード・マウス無しの三重苦でもセットアップする方法](https://karaage.hatenadiary.jp/entry/2015/07/15/080000)
[Enable ssh and connect to a wifi network without a keyboard or a screen - Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/66949/95039)